# How to get beeping on boot to stop?

Tags: boot, sound, 15.10

I recently tried installing Ubuntu 15.10, and for all the trouble of "root directory" during installation, I decided not to install. But every time I boot (*from usb*), the boot menu shown in the image below pops up and it beeps really loud. This is really embarrassing in public and would like to know how to make it boot this menu SILENTLY.

[image]

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

is the result of running the following command in linux terminal:

```
cat /etc/default/grub
```

EDIT: I have booted twice after my fix and it was fine. On the third fixed boot, I had large problems, about the graphics stuff not being recognized. I shut down and turned it back on, and some other stuff appeared in the middle of boot, saying stuff that I can not currently recall. Yet again off and on. The boot went ok. I am in fact editing this from the computer with Ubu 15.10 on it, but this time the problem is ANYTHING to do with my user password.

Examples (what i have found so far) are:
Adding/deleting users. The "unlock" button in setings to add/del users requires password, everytime i put in my password, (i have tried it i know at least 15 times, so i know im putting in the right password)it tells me that "Your authentication attempt was unsuccessful. Please try again."

2- SUDO: i have edited my .bashrc to automatically log me into sudo (yes, with a password.). Whenever i put in my (correct) password, i get an error:

```
tyler is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported
```

thats all ive done so far, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: are you booting from USB everytime?

Comment: @TyGuy1016 Can you run `cat /etc/default/grub` in Terminal and edit your question with the output? That'll help me answer your question :)

Comment: kk ill try, im currently on windows, ill need to boot it up, so it will take a minute

Comment: if it tells you anything, i havent edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the output of `cat /etc/default/grub` there is no config causing the beep, as `GRUB_INIT_TUNE` is commented out.

However, this can be caused by a key being held down prior to the GRUB menu showing up. If you recently spilled anything on your laptop or eaten near it, you might have a stuck key. Not stuck enough to show up in the full OS, but enough to cause GRUB to beep.

If you pop off the key-caps on the keyboard and clean underneath them, that might resolve your issue as sometimes little bits of food (or even just stuff from regular use) can get underneath the keys.

**EDIT**: We were able to figure out the issue in chat.

OP had to edit the `/cdrom/isolinux/menu.cfg` file and edit the `menu title Installer boot menu^G` line by removing the `^G` from the end. He then restarted, and the issue was resolved.

Comment: It's not that. It does it on every computer I have boot Ubu from.

Comment: @TyGuy1016 I may have another solution, but I'll have to make a bootable USB to test it out. As for your second comment the boot menu is the boot menu. [GRUB is the boot loader](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB)

Comment: @TyGuy1016 I was going to create the USB stick so I could see if there is a separate GRUB config file stored on the USB stick that's different than the one in `/etc/default/grub`. I won't be able to get an answer to you in regards to that for a couple of hours. Is the entire installation on the USB stick? As for your age, there's nothing wrong with it! I've been involved with Linux/Ubuntu since I was 12 and on this site since I was 13.

Comment: ok yes the entire install is on the 16gb DUO LINK flash drive (its the kind that has one end for apple lightning connector and one for standard usb

Comment: Well, I might have found another solution. Try editing the `isolinux/menu.cfg` file and looking for a line that looks like this: `menu title Installer boot menu^G`. Try deleting the `^G` from the end of the line, it might resolve your issue. As for my age, I'm 16 currently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33673/discussion-between-tyguy1016-and-rpi-awesomeness).